# Create Google Adwords ad from external page

Tags: external, google-ads-api

Is it possible to create a Google Adwords ad from an external page executing a script with certain parameters that change with each execution?

I am asking if the only way to create a new campaign is creating it from Google page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google AdWords Scripts from the bulk operations tab. There you can code in javascript and create ads in bulk or if you cannot code in javascript you can create a template in excel and then mass import in Google AdWords editor and mass upload them into your account.